# Display Patches using intel GPU with xorg

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, xorg.conf

I have a laptop with a Nvidia GPU and Intel GPU.
I wanted to divert all processes away from the Nvidia in nvidia-smi towards my intel gpu.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
```

So I created a xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Driver          "intel"
    BusId           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Device          "intel"
EndSection
```

This indeed does divert all processes away from my nvidia GPU.  However, my once plain black background now looks like this:

[new background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYLwB.png)

Perhaps there other parameters I need to put into this xorg.conf file?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

solved issue but making the following change

```
Driver "modesetting"
```

but now I cannot run anything on the dGPU, is there a way to set xorg.conf to run a secondary GPU when necessary?